# Want to cancel OnActionExecuted for Custom action filter created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I have created a custom action filter, that runs some analtyics code on each action that has the filer.

On one controller's action, on the basis of one boolean flag, I would want to skip the OnActionExecuted code of that filter applied on this action.

I see Cancelled property in that in OnActionExecuted, but not sure how i can make this true in Controller's action.

One possibility is to have some value in RouteData, on the basis of that flag and then check that value if thats true then simple cancel this. But I am not sure this is the correct approach.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: In OnActionExecuted method, you have a OnActionExecutedContext in which all the information about the action is stored. You can get the action name or any other specific thing from this context and can create a check accordingly in OnActionExecuted method. I think this hack can help..